# basic question on parsin json results with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

after researching A LOT I found myself in the to create a question here.

Usually I make an API call to a server and it returns like this

```
{
"codigo": 200,
"pessoas": [
    {
        "idpessoa": "5",
        "idpessoa_legado": null,
        "ativo": "S",
        "ativo_painel": "S",
        "ativo_login": "S",
        "idpais": "3",
        "idestado": "25",
        "idcidade": "5370",
        "documento": "12345678999"
     }
]}
```

And whenever I need to call it up, I use a function like this:

```
user.set('documento', resp.pessoas[0].documento);
```

the *"resp"* part is a function that connects with the API. *user.set* sets the result to the new variable. It works fine as it should.

But I stumbled uppon an API that looks like this:

```
{
"510": {
    "situacao": {
        "idsituacao": "3",
        "situacao": "Vendida"
    },
    "imobiliaria": {
        "email": null,
        "telefone": null,
        "cnpj": null
    },
    "unidade": {
        "empreendimento": "Artesano Galleria",
        "idempreendimento_int": "19",
        "etapa": "ETAPA 01",
...
```

I've never seen a json response without `[]` signs. This one has only `{}` signs. I have no idea on how to call it and get the value from `510.unidade.idempreendimento_int`
Another problem is that it already starts with its own ID.

Help please! :)

Comment: Do you know the ID beforehand? You could try to use resp['510'][ID]['idempreendimento_int']

Comment: `[]` is for arrays, `{}` is for objects. There's nothing unusual about nested objects like this.

Comment: @Barmar, my question is: how to call them?

Comment: @NicholasWong, i don't know it yet. It' a really confusing and bad documented api. Thanks though!

Comment: If `response` is the name of the variable, `response['510'].unidade. idempreendimento_int`

Comment: @Barmar OMG, it works. Thank you so much. I don't know, I think this question was closed before I could get your answer as Solved. But thanks a lot dude. You're awesome.

Comment: Yes, I closed it first. Since it seemed like you didn't understand how to apply the solutions there to your problem, I posted the comment. Did I misunderstand what happened?